# What's the probability of that matrix multiplication can exchange?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two n-order matrices $A,B$,whose elements follow the Gaussian distribution on R.what's the probability that $AB=BA$?

Comment: Probability among what input space?

Comment: @Daniel n-dimensional complex linear space. My linear algebra teacher asked us this question,I think we can put this question in this space to consider.

Comment: We need to know what sort of distribution the entries in your [random matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_matrix) follow.  In an extreme case, the random matrices are guaranteed to be diagonal so the probability could be $100\%$ while in another extreme case $A$ and $B$ follow different distributions such that it guarantees they are noncommutative giving a probability of $0\%$.  Until you provide more information, it could be anywhere between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz The matrix can be any n-dimensional matrix.It doesn't have anything special.

Comment: In the case of independent entries and Gaussian distribution the answer is zero, since the entries are contained in an algebraic variety.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Could you please give a more detailed explanation?I haven't learned the concept variety...

Comment: You haven't seemed to learn the concept "random" either yet... you should probably start there

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm sorry.the matrix have $n^2$ entries.Every entry follow the uniform distribution on R.Can this be clear enough?

Comment: An algebraic variety is a set in $\mathbb R^n$ that is defined by polynmial equations (multivariate polynomials!). That is $V = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n) : p_j(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = 0\text{ for $j=1,\ldots,m$}\}$. If $V\neq\mathbb R^n$ you might imagine such a set as a union of hypersurfaces of dimension at most $n-1$. So, a generic vector will not lie in $V$.

Comment: @Joker Chair: There is no uniform distribution on $\mathbb R$. I guess the Gaussian distribution is meant.

Comment: I think the answer is, that under any reasonable definition of random, the answer is zero.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: I think so, too, since the question was asked in a linear algebra class. I guess the main task is to see that the set of these matrix pairs is very small in $\mathbb C^{n^2}\times\mathbb C^{n^2}$.